# How to apply Two-Factor ANOVA in SAS when I only know the counts of each outcome?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, sas

I am confused about how to apply two-factor ANOVA when I get actually no real data, but only count for each outcome, because the dependent variable is categorical, and is binary (only 0 and 1), and I get the count of 0 and count of 1. The data is like this:

```
Gender | Group | Outcome | Count    
M        A        0        490  
M        A        1        10 
M        B        0        475    
M        B        1        25    
F        A        0        440   
F        A        1        60    
F        B        0        455    
F        B        1        45
```

So this is a Balanced design. What is the code to apply two-factor ANOVA in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Asking for code is [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. If you rephrase it to ask about the statistical issue rather than SAS code it might be on topic.

Comment: I am voting to keep it open because there is a statistical issue in the question even though it doesn't explicitly ask about it.

Comment: @T.E.G. Hi T.E.G thank you for the noticing. Sorry for the inappropriate question, not quite familiar with this site. I'll find somewhere else to post it next time. Again appreciate that.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you very much, for this is my very first time asking a question here, and this won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Because your response variable is composed of counts of a binary response (0 or 1), logistic regression would be an appropriate model to use.  I suspect you don't want to use traditional OLS regression (e.g. `proc anova`, or `proc glm`) with this kind of data.

I'm no longer a SAS person, but I remember `proc logistic` being pretty straight-forward to use.  I think you will not need to change the format of your data; I believe the `freq` statement can be used with your *Count* variable to let SAS know, e.g. how many *M*, *A*, *outcome 0* observations you had.

For example, try the following, with the caveat that I'm not a SAS person:

```
proc logistic data=D1;
    freq Count;
    class Gender Group;
    model Outcome = Gender Group Gender*Group;
run;
```

Comment: This looks reasonable, so will it still work while the outcome has more than two categorical results? e.g. 0 ~ 9? Thank you!

Comment: The model would be different if the categories are ordered (ordinal regression) or if they are un-ordered nominal (multinominal regression).  It looks like `proc logistic` is used with ordinal regression [SAS support](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect061.htm), but that `proc catmod` is used more often in the case of multinomial regression.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sal Mangiafico's Answer, I find that to apply an ANOVA test in `PROC GLM`, the `freq` option can also be used.

```
data work.temp;
    input gender variant result count;
        datalines;
        0 0 0 490
        0 0 1 10
        0 1 0 475
        0 1 1 25
        1 0 0 460
        1 0 1 40
        1 1 0 495
        1 1 1 5
        ;
run;

proc glm data = temp;
    title2 '2-way ANOVA, assume no interaction';
    freq count;
    class gender variant;
    model result = gender variant;
    means gender variant;
    lsmeans gender variant;
run;
quit;
```

And this works well.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to CV

So your data is basically in a slightly summarized form (it's actually in [wide](https://stanford.edu/~ejdemyr/r-tutorials/wide-and-long/) form), which doesn't really work in most statistical programs (for ANOVA at least).

What you need to do is *reshape* your data from wide to long. The first line of your data looks like this

```
Gender | Group | Outcome | Count    
M        A        0        490
```

Rather than having a `count` column, you instead want to have

```
Gender | Group | Outcome    
M        A        0
```

But repeated identically 490 times.

You would then have

```
Gender | Group | Outcome    
M        A        1
```

Repeated ten times...

And so on through your whole dataset. There are a variety of tools to achieve this, so I recommend you search for those.

Once your data has been changed, then the GLM tools in SAS should work fine

Comment: With an outcome variable that is counts of a binary response, I suspect traditional OLS regression isn't the best method for analysis.

Comment: Yeah... Maybe you are right since I wanna use an ANOVA. Thank you!

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico, you'll notice that nowhere did I recommend to use ols regression. The bottom of my answer even references a glm...

Comment: Ah.  In SAS, "GLM" is often used for "general linear model", as in "PROC GLM", hence my misinterpretation.

Comment: Ah, sweet as. Yeah I generally interpret GLM as generalized linear model. Cheers!